# How to get complete text inside page-footer from div

Tags: selenium

How to get complete text inside page-footer in the below case.

```
<div class="page-footer">
  <span >Environment: </span>
  <span > test</span>
  <span >Version: </span>
  <span > 0.1.56</span>
</div>
```

Comment: are you facing any problem ? please update the question with your code trial and exception as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a text from following div using Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386581/how-to-get-a-text-from-following-div-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: @JayadevBS Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **CSS_SELECTOR** :

```
div.page-footer span
```

this will select all the span which are inside the **div** with class `page-footer`.

In case, you are using JAVA as a binding language :

```
String allText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.page-footer span")).getText();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to extract all the visible text

In Java,

**getText()** method will return the visible text of an element (i.e. not hidden by CSS)

```
string footerText=driver.findElement(By.className("page-footer")).getText();
```

In C#,

```
var footerText=_driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("page-footer")).Text;
```